# Could I import a QT .pro file in visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, qt, relative-path, qmake, visual-c++-2010

I have a QT 4.5.1 project configuration file like this

```
DEFINES           += WIN32
OBJECTS_DIR       = ../tmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS      += -static-libgcc

LIBS              += $(GDIR)/win-mingw/bin/libserverlib.a
LIBS              += -lws2_32   -lpthread
INCLUDEPATH       += ../../lib/src    // need here to know how to write the relative path in mscv
LIBS              +=  -L ../../folder1/folder2/lib/file_32.lib
```

How could I convert this configuration into a MSVC 2010 one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this without the addin. It generates the visual studio solution file and vcxproj

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-platform-notes.html#creating-visual-studio-project-files

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Visual Studio Add-in to import Qt projects into Visual Studio.

[Visual Studio Add-in for Qt4](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource.exe)

[Visual Studio Add-in for Qt5](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.4-opensource.exe)